# Why do JFrame's update, revalidate, and repaint not update the window?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I am trying to create a window frame to display a game window. I extended `JFrame` in my `GameWindow` class and created two methods: `drawBackground`, which fills the screen with a solid rectangle, and `drawGrid`, which draws successive lines using a for-loop to make a grid. Here is my code.

```java
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

    // instance variables, etc.

    public GameWindow(int width, Color bgColor) {
        super();

        // ...

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void drawBackground() {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(bgColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getWidth());

        // I suspect that the problem is here...
        this.update(g);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void drawGrid() {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int i = tileWidth; i < TILE_COUNT * tileWidth; i += tileWidth) {

            g.drawLine(0, i * tileWidth, this.getWidth(), i * tileWidth);
            g.drawLine(i * tileWidth, 0, i * tileWidth, this.getHeight());

        }

        // ... and here.
        this.update(g);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
        g.dispose();
    }

}
```

However, when I try to test this class in a program like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameWindow game = new GameWindow(700);

        game.drawBackground();
        game.drawGrid();
    }
}
```

the frame appears on screen but remains blank; neither the background nor the grid is being drawn. I tried `Graphics g = this.getGraphics()` to `this.getContentPane().getGraphics()`. I also tried using many different combinations and orders in `drawBackground` and `drawGrid` of `revalidate`, `update`, etc. None of these attempts seemed to work. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Graphics g = this.getGraphics();` would be a good place to start.  Since `repaint` just schedules a paint pass to occur with the `RepaintManager`, all the code using `getGraphics` will simply be ignored.

This is not how custom painting works.  `getGraphics` can return `null` and is, at best, a snapshot of the last paint cycle, anything you paint to it will be wiped clean on the next paint cycle.

Also, don't `dispose` of a `Graphics` context you did not create, on some systems this will stop other components from been able to use it

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a better understanding into how painting works and how you should work with it.

You're also, likely, going to want to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for ideas on creating a "main loop" to update the UI at constant rate, as Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe

Comment: Huh.. just noticed your '300K' rep. label is **very** imminent. Just 75(?) more rep.

Comment: BTW - you have loads of rep to spare. I challenge you to, once hitting 300K, post a bounty of 500 on an excellent answer on a Java related question. An answer from a person with <100K rep. You up for it? I'd really like to see the answer you choose. And, added bonus, it might take you some effort (and time) to find a worthy answer - so I'd get a chance to get in a few answers on Swing questions before you get to them. 

Comment: Would +50 if I could; links were very useful, thanks!